# Get image tag inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that needs to download a specific version of a software from an URL with the `ENV` command. Such as:

In `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV sw_ver=1.2.3

ADD https://some_address/_name_$sw_ver /some_dir
```

The build command is analogous to this:

```
docker build -t my_image:1.2.3 .
```

Now, it would be great if instead of setting the `ENV` variable, I could build different images for different versions of the software by simply varying the tag in my `docker build` command. So is it possible to read the tag number inside the `Dockerfile` and use it as a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a bash script with the tag wanted in the first positional argument of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker build --build-arg sw-ver=$1 -t my_image:$1 .
```

Then tun the script:

```
script.sh 1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use build-args to change env vars during build time.

`docker build --build-arg sw_ver=4.5.6 -t my_image:1.2.3 .`

[Docker documentation about build-args](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg)